# GitLab Container to GKE (Kubernetes) deployment

Tags: gitlab

Hello I have a problem with GitLab CI/CD. I'm trying to deploy container to Kubernetes on GKE however I'm getting an error:
**This job failed because the necessary resources were not successfully created.**

I created a service account with kube-admin rights and created cluster via GUI of GitLab so its fully itegrated. But when I run the job it still doesn't work..
by the way I use kubectl get pods in gitlab-ci file just to test if kubernetes is repsonding.

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

docker-build:
  # Use the official docker image.
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  # Default branch leaves tag empty (= latest tag)
  # All other branches are tagged with the escaped branch name (commit ref slug)
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}"

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
  script:
    - kubectl get pods
  environment:
    name: production
    kubernetes:
      namespace: test1
```

Any Ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

namespace should be removed.

GitLab creates own namespace for every project